# Error WPF signalr 1 tras migrar del framework.net 4.5.2 a 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf

Ayuda por favor!
Tengo una app hecha en WPF que incluye cefsharp y signalr 1.2.2. Esta app fué hecha en el framework .net 4.5.2 
En windows 10 y 7 funciona bien. 
El problema surge cuando hago la migración al framework .net 4.0 para poder correrla en windows XP.
Tuve que hacer muchos cambios y quedaron funcionando pero me encuentro con un warning que no me permite compilar:

> La referencia principal "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client,
>   Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" no se pudo resolver porque tiene una
>   dependencia indirecta en el ensamblado "Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed", el
>   cual se compiló con la versión de .NET Framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". Esta es una versión posterior a la
>   versión de .NET Framework de destino actual
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". Notificator

Por lo que puedo entender hay algun inconveniente con **Newtonsoft.Json**, pero honestamente no puedo encontrar la solucion. De hecho, cree una app básica con las mismas librerias y referencias pero sin el código y tras compilar funciona..

Agradeceria que puedan orientarme

Aclaracion: soy muy nuevo en este tema, estoy modificando una aplicacion que me dieron para modificar, si tuviera el conocimiento la haria desde cero

Comment: ¡Madre santa! Hacer un downgrade de .net 4.5 hacia 4.0 para hacer compatible con Windows XP es una mala idea... Hay muchas cosas que se implementaron a partir de Windows Vista en adelante, vas a tener muchos problemas... "The .NET Framework 4 is supported on Windows XP, however, it will not run apps that require .NET Framework 4.5 or later versions." https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/

Comment: Revisa este enlace: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=signal+R+windows+xp&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.4 (lo digo en buen plan) Entre más rápido te acostumbres a leer, más rápido vas a aprender.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo he solucionado haciendo el reinstall de los packages. Es una app chica. Muchas gracias por las respuestas

Comment: De nada :D ¡Que alegría! bien por ti, por un momento pensé que se trataba de alguna app grande debido a que utilizas signalR, si la respuesta del hermano Leodev funcionó, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check que está debajo de las flechas de votaciones. Bienvenido a SOes por cierto :D

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora marco, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newtonsoft tiene versiones de su librería JSON para casi todas las versiones de .NET Framework, puedes buscarla en su web o reinstalar el ensamblado desde la consola de administración de paquetes usando

```
update-package -reinstall
```

Esto descargará todas las versiones del ensamblado, incluida la 4.0 que es la que tu necesitas

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda. Funcionó totalmente. Aparentemente era un problema de versiones..